# How to import multiple swift games under one framework and create a main menu for them?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

I wanna implement a game platform and have implemented three swift games(by using single view project) individually. Now I would like to implement a main menu that has three buttons: Game A, Game B and Game C. When users press the button, the correspondent game will start. Could you please tell me how to do that with less efforts? Like Java, we could create a jar for each project and call them later in other java project. Is there similar way in swift? Thanks.

Comment: Understand, no matter how you do this, it still will be **one** app (or bundle ID) in the app store.

Comment: we wanted it to be one app. Do you know some ways to do that?

Comment: Not if you want it on the App Store. I recommend - before going too much further - investigating App Store policies, iOS app sandboxing, and pricing. The only way I can think of doing it still involves **one** app or bundle ID and a very large project, where each game within the app is an IAP, or In-App Purchase. But seriously, before wasting a lot of hard work and time, read up on what Apple allows in their app store. One more thing - check out what *is* out there - if you find a good example of what you want, find out how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the code create an unique project. You should create a segue in every buttonTapped method. To do this create a segue in the Storyboard (drag from one VC to another), then click on it and give it an identifier. In the buttonTapped method use performSegueWithIdentifier("your_identifier") and that is it.

Edit:
Ok, i'll try to be more specific to help you. To create the app you want you will need all the code in the same project (all about the three games).
So, in Xcode, you will have to create four viewController (three for the games and another one for the menu). To do this go to your Main.storyboard file (you have it when you create the project by default) and drag the viewController view (right down). Then, you will have to create a custom class for every one of them (inherits from UIViewController). Then in the storyBoard again you choose your custom class (the one you've created) for every viewController.

**Talking about the segues**, you can learn how to create them [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2).
It's basically a way to move between your viewControllers. When you create one you have to use `performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender:  nil)`
Put that code inside the buttonTapped method of your button (learn all about it [here](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios/storyboards-outlets-actions/)).

Well, let me know if you don't understand something. Good luck!

Comment: hi. I am a beginner on ios. Could you please tell me more about that? or is there any some videos or materials about how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SpriteKit scene as a main menu for your game, with three different buttons for transition to each game scene. You can create a title using the SKLabelNode and use a Sprite or Shape Node as buttons for your scene.

I experienced adding UIButtons and UILabels to a SpriteKit Scene can get very technical with the problem of positioning them. Due to the fact that the UI Objects are positioned on the view and not on the SpriteKit Scene directly. You can use a SKSpriteNode as a Button and the SKLabelNode as a Title, For a menu scene.

A Sprite kit scene is placed on the UIView and is scaled depending on the scale mode you define. Apples default scale mode .aspectFill requires no adjustment to Sprite kit objects positioning on different Phone device screen sizes.

This is a Custom Class of a SKSpriteNode with the same functionality as a button.

```
 import Foundation
 import SpriteKit

 class ButtonLabelNode : SKSpriteNode {

let buttonPressed: () -> ()

init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize, text: String, buttonPressed: @escaping () -> ()) {

self.buttonPressed = buttonPressed

super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)

let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Futura")
label.fontSize = 50
label.fontColor = SKColor.red
label.position = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
label.zPosition = 1
label.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
label.text = text
self.addChild(label)

self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

     self.alpha = 0.8

    }

   override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

   self.alpha = 1.0

    buttonPressed()
    }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

   }
```

When a touch begins on the SpriteNode the alpha decreases to 0.8 and back to 1.0 as the touch ends, Giving it the same visual affect of a UIButton. In the overridden function 'touchesEnded' there is a function that will be called every time the button is pressed, that function is added in the initializer and can be initialized in your game scene.

```
      override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

let labelNode = LabelNode(texture: nil, color: .white, size: CGSize.init(width: 200, height: 100), text: "Play", buttonPressed: playButton)
labelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

self.addChild(labelNode)

}

func playButton() 
{
print("play")
 }
```

If you would like to have buttons of different shapes or a unique shape you can sub class a ShapeNode instead of a SpriteNode and Implement the same Functionality, Here is a example of how to Create a Circle ShapeNode as a button.

```
     import Foundation
     import SpriteKit

     class SKShapeButton: SKShapeNode {

    init(circleOfRadius: CGFloat) {
       super.init()

    let diameter = circleOfRadius * 2.0
    self.path = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.init(x: 0.0 - circleOfRadius, y: 0.0 - circleOfRadius), size: CGSize(width: diameter, height: diameter)), transform: nil)
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.alpha = 0.8

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.alpha = 1.0
}

 }
```

Then just make a instance of it in your game scene.

```
      override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let shapeButton = SKShapeButton(circleOfRadius: 50)
    shapeButton.fillColor = .red

    shapeButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    self.addChild(shapeButton)
     }
```

To transition to each of your game scene's you can implement the code that is in the Game View Controller swift file, That presents the provided game scene.

```
      if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
```